# opencv saving video python vs raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am running a script using opencv to record and save a video from a usb camera. Using the same code on my laptop and a raspberry pi 3B, the laptop saves the video and I can watch it back but the raspberry pi video ends up with an error (0xc10100be) saying that "the file isn't playable becuase the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect or the file corrupt". Can Raspberry Pi not save an MP4 file, is there something I need to install on raspberry pi to save videos or is it likely something else?

Thanks.

```
import cv2

video_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # opens camera for video capture, 0 for inbuilt camera, 1 for USB cam
width = int(video_cam.get(3))
height = int(video_cam.get(4))
size = (width, height)
print(size)
print(type(video_cam))
print(video_cam.isOpened()) # returns true if video capturig initialised, means VideoCapture construcor succeeded

out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20, size, True)

while video_cam.isOpened():
    check, frame = video_cam.read() # takes, decodes and returns video frame
    if check==True:
        out.write(frame) # writes frame to mp4/avi file for saving
        cv2.imshow("image", frame) # display in image, takes 2 inputs, window name being displayed in and the actual image

    # waitkey(): if use (0) displays still image and image remains until key is pressed
    #            if use (1) frame displayed for 1ms before closing
    # keep streaming until press q 0xFF - means the ASCII input, waitKey returns 32 bit integer value but we only want last 8 bits
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'): 
            break
    else: 
        break

video_cam.release() # closes video camera
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use ffmpeg instead. -- you failed to check `assert out.isOpened()`

Comment: ffmpeg instead of OpenCV? Also I checked whether my out variable opened and there was no issue with that

Comment: does your code break out of the loop immediately, or do you actually see the imshow window and a camera feed? -- what exact size does the resulting file have? if it's not just a handful of kilobytes, can you share such a file that you say isn't playable? -- I don't see the usual issues in your code so this might be harder to debug. -- try .avi with MJPG codec. that is built into OpenCV and always works. if that _doesn't_ work, it's the code in principle. if it works, check out `print(cv.getBuildInformation())`, specifically the Video I/O section

Comment: I found the bug in the end, I had copied this code over to my pi board wrong and had the width and height the wrong way round, very silly. However the frame rate on the Pi is much lower than on the laptop and it seems to be due to the out.write() function. I get <10FPS for the pi and 30FPS for my laptop . Is there a way to increase my frame rate with the PI whilst still saving the data?